# Tactics people with electricity powers would develop against people with water powers during a death tournament, and vice versa?

Tags: magic, tactics

For centuries, on the day the moon would turn a blood red, a portal would open across various worlds. Chosen warriors from these worlds would enter the portal, usually at most five people per world, then enter a realm that was the center of various dimensions, and where a tournament unlike any other would take place. The purpose of the tournament is simple: to find the very best warrior across multiple realities.

Rules:

During the tournament, warriors from across the realms would do battle in one-on-one combat, and if they win, they would go on to face their next opponent the following day after getting their injuries healed by the healers the tournament employs. The match-ups are almost always random, with all of the warriors being divided into various brackets and the champions of these brackets going on to the finals, and the locations of the fights are never the same.

For each match, the two warriors are teleported to different locations across dimensions; sometimes it could be a valley, with the warriors having to wander through it just to find their opponent, though in these cases both warriors have to make an active effort to find their opponent or else they are disqualified, sometimes it can take place in a decaying building that is about to collapse, or even in a dojo with the warriors being only a few feet apart.

Warriors can bring weapons, but only those they have trained extensively with throughout their lives, so no bringing in weapons that would come in handy against a certain race whose weaknesses they know. In the event one warrior tries to run and hide, whether it's to try and heal their injuries or come up with a different strategy, they must come back to fight the other warrior within twenty minutes, with a “timer” appearing in their heads provided by the “host” of the event, or else they automatically lose.

At the end of each match, when the judges declare that a warrior can no longer battle, the winning warrior has the option of either killing their defeated opponent, or letting them live. Most people chose the former.

Combatants:

With the tournament going on for centuries, rivalries have formed across dimensions, as a lot of races are selected again and again due to producing such excellent warriors. One such rivalry is with the Luceras, magic humans that developed the power to manipulate electricity in all its forms after a catastrophic event that nearly brought an end to their world, and the Moranas, another race of magic humans that have the ability to manipulate water since their water Goddess came down to their world and blessed them with her powers.

The Luceras can generate pure electricity from their bodies, able to conjure up miniature bolts of lighting in their palms, and launch them at blinding speed. They can channel their electricity around their bodies to the point it acts like a barrier, protecting them from physical attacks, to a degree, and electrocuting anyone that touches them. Finally, they can absorb any type of electricity into their bodies, and then use it to make their own attacks stronger, and can manipulate the electricity in non-sentient objects.

The Luceras weaknesses are that they can’t generate an infinite amount of electricity from nothing, as the more they create, the more tired they become. If they produce a large amount of volts per attack, they must take anywhere from one to a few minutes, depending on the intensity, to regain their "stamina" before they can launch another attack. The electric shield they use can also only tank one good hit, say something with the force of a bullet, before it crumbles, and it gets harder and harder to reconstruct it the more times its been dispelled. They also have to be careful about how much electricity they absorb, as this might cause them to “overload” their sense and cause them to collapse.

The Moronas have the power to control water in all its forms. They can shape and drag it from any source, like the air, with the only exception being animals and other human beings, so they can’t just cause another person to literally erupt with blood; although, they can manipulate the blood and water that’s in their own bodies. They can make the water they control either scalding or freezing, essentially making it either boiling water or literal blocks of ice. And if they have enough time and water, they can even form large, wave-like attacks that can completely submerge a person, and then form the receding water into a large, orb-shaped prison that slowly drowns the person.

The Moronas weaknesses are that, while their magic does most of the heavy lifting, using excessive amounts of water drains them of their strength, and as mentioned previously, they can’t manipulate the water inside of other humans or animals.

The Question:

The Luceras and The Moronas have fought warriors from each other's race for years, and once again, they are matched up against the other. This time, in the streets of an empty city a few hours after a rainstorm, with puddles of water scattered throughout as well as plenty of abandoned cars and stores. So, keeping in mind all the previously stated information, I want to ask: What kind of tactics would these two races develop against each other?

Comment: Seems like a Lucera can turn themself into lightning, zap themself inside their Morona opponent, and reform their solid body inside, thereby exploding the Morona. Fast and gruesome match, the Lucera needs a shower afterwards.

Comment: I should probably change that then.

Comment: This question is too broad. Pick one combat location (asking for them all makes the question too story based and vulnerable to closure). Keep in mind that water conducts electricity - which puts the Morona at a HUGE disadvantage. Therefore, please explain exactly how long the Lucera can keep up the fight and how long he/she must rest to recuperate power (drawing from the surroundings is too story based unless you specify it as a condition of the question). frankly, it's not a large wave attack you want, its an ultra high pressure pencil-thin attack. AKA, bullet.

Comment: @JBH Oh, I see. Is this better?

Comment: That basically Naruto suiton vs. raiton.

Comment: Better. Thanks! It's always desirable to provide all the details you can think of. That guarantees no closure and results in higher quality answers.

Comment: Why would anyone compete?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the decisions of individuals in your world, rather than asking about building your world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Morona**

The Morona strategy is very simple. First, they wear specialized armor designed specifically for conducting and grounding electrical attacks away from them. That gives them the ability to survive getting struck by lightning. That's their defense. It's simple and efficient. Also within the rules - there's nothing against specialized armor defenses and even if there was, the Morona would be training with this armor from childbirth anyway.

Their offense is also relatively simple. Track down the Lucera and surround him with water that you've dumped metal powder into. If the Lucera tries to use electricity, it'll be conducted through the water back into him. True, it'll make the Lucera stronger (somehow) but if it's kept up, the energy discharged into the water will boil the Lucera alive. At that point, the Morona approaches and shoots him in the chest with a non-conductive harpoon gun.

**Lucera**

The Lucera strategy is a bit different. Given that the Morona can use armor to avoid electrical attacks, Lucera can try for a similar strategy with breathing masks and armor of their own, but it won't help against being caged in water. So the Luceras use a different strategy altogether - sniping. Given they can generate prodigious amounts of electricity, they can power a railgun, so that's what they bring to a fight. A railgun.

The Lucera strategy is simple. Find the Morona first and blast them into small pieces with a single railgun-powered sniper round.

Ultimately, this then turns into a game of cat-and-mouse. The Lucera possesses the advantage at range, but should his position ever be revealed, then the Morona can go after him with water attacks and use water for cover moving to him.

Answer (score 0):

As in real life, for both side the best strategy is to develop or buy weapons that negate any physical advantage. A simple rifle would be a decisive win for either side.